# How can i create dynamic content collapsible in jquery mobile after fetching the content from database?

Tags: jquery

I have some values in the database.I want to construct a collapsible list view based on that.How to do the list view by adding all CSS properties? Kindly answer my doubt.

Answer (score 0):

A bit more details of your implementation could be a good bonus :)

But if i understood you correctly you could do it like this, based on jQuery Mobile documentation:
http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/lists/docs-lists.html

```
// This is your HTML list
<ul data-role="listview">
    <li><a href="acura.html">Acura</a></li>
    <li><a href="audi.html">Audi</a></li>
    <li><a href="bmw.html">BMW</a></li>
</ul>

// This is where you fetch data from database and add them to list
function addToList (listId) {
    var list = document.getElementById(listId);

    // Iterate over items found in database here and add them to DOM
    for ( var i = 0 ; i < dataSource.length ; i += 1 ) {
        liElem = document.createElement('li');
        liElem.textContent = dataSource[i];
        list.appendChild(liElem);
    }
    // Refresh the list
    $(list).listview('refresh');
}
```

**Simple Demo:**
http://jsfiddle.net/dR7fx/1/